# lpdwNumberOfBytesRead of InternetReadFile turns into zero while download is still commencing

Tags: c++, download, wininet

I use InternetReadFile to download file.

But when downloading large file(over 1GB), it will stop downloading.

I find out that dwBytesRead will turn into zero unexpectedly, but InternetReadFile returns TRUE.

No matter I set **READ_BUFFER_SIZE** to 4K or 16K.

The following is my code:

```
while(1) 
{

    memset(tszReadBuffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE); //clear the buffer
    bReadFile = InternetReadFile(hInternetOpenURL, tszReadBuffer, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, &dwBytesRead);
    if(!bReadFile)
        return 0;

    llNowSize += dwBytesRead;  //calculate progress
    if (dwBytesRead == 0)    
        break;  //finish download
    bWriteFile = WriteFile(hCreateFile, tszReadBuffer, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesWrite, NULL);               
    if(!bWriteFile)
        return 0;                       
}
```

Thanks in advance.